# Import Vue JS component from outside project dir

Tags: vue.js, webpack, frontend

I (want to) have a project structure like this:

```
project
    app1
        package.json
        src/SomeComponent1  
    app2
        package.json
        src/SomeComponent2
    common-components
        SharedComponent
```

What I wish is to easily be able to import `SharedComponent` into `SomeComponent1` or `SomeComponent2`. **This is not possible (many errors are raised while doing so.)**

I know there are more elegant ways to do this but I don't wish to introduce all the infrastructure and extra maintenance work around deploying `'common'` to artifactory and having extra jenkins pipeline, etc...

Editing Webpack through vue.config.js would be best if it is possible.

Comment: What kind of errors appear during import? If you go with importing via path `../../common-components/SharedComponent`, there should be no problem. Though, it can be simplified.

Comment: I've been getting some errors for PostCSS issues.. I don't have that pc right with me, but I've replicated same project(s) structure with simple demo apps, and after adding package.json (with ~same contents that non-common projects have) it seem to be ok. Looks like if you are importing outside-of-project components, you need to have configuration for eslint/postcss/etc.. in this lonely folder where common components reside. I will verify this on Monday

Comment: Hi, I have the same task, found some solution to avoid eslint errors?